# Java WebFlux/Reactor - Filter a Flux<List<String>> with items only found in Mono<Set<String>>

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I'm new to WebFlux/Reactor and having trouble wrapping my head around how to write this piece of code. Basically, I have a Flux which has a nested List foo and a Mono<Set> bar and I'd like to only return items in foo that are contained in bar.

```
// these two lines are representations of what the data looks like
Flux<CategoryModel> foo = { Permissions = [ "UserRole1"] } // List<String>
Mono<Set<String>> bar = [ "UserRole1", "UserRole2" ]; 

var filteredFoo = foo.filter(m -> m.getPermissions().stream().anyMatch(perm -> bar.block().contains(foo)));
```

The problem with the above block of code is the `.block()` on the `contains()` and I don't want to block. Not sure how to change this to have non blocking but still check if bar contains the perm item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question directly - don't use `filter()`, use `filterWhen()`, which filters based on a publisher rather than a set value:

```
foo.filterWhen(m -> bar.map(set -> m.getPermissions().stream().anyMatch(perm -> set.contains(foo))));
```

Note that your code as-written is a bit odd however and I've just translated it directly - but it doesn't make much sense at the moment for a couple of reasons:

- You're streaming over the permissions but not actually using the permission in your `anyMatch()` lambda at present - so currently your code could be simplified to:

  ```
  foo.filterWhen(m -> bar.map(set -> set.contains(foo)));
  ```
- Even given the above, you're checking if your set contains `foo`, which is the flux itself, so there's no reasonable situation in which that would ever be true.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this solution worked, my code was a bit different so I understand what you mean in your last point about checking to see if the set contains foo directly. Appreciate the prompt help on this one, really need to get more comfortable with webflux.

Comment: @MannfromReno No worries, happy to help. Webflux / reactive stuff is a different beast - it really does take some getting used to and a completely different style of programming, so certainly don't feel bad if you're missing things like this when starting out!

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the final content of your mono so that you can filter your flux, so just wait for it:

```java
var filteredFoo = bar.flatMapMany(b -> foo.filter(f -> f.getPermissions().stream().anyMatch(b::contains)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll give this a shot as well.